# Aligning in java

Tags: java

I am trying to print the multiplication table using java 19.0.2, using the following code:

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(" 5 * "+ String.format("%2n", i) + " = " + (5*i)); 
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatWidthException: 2
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.checkText(Formatter.java:3313)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2996)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2839)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2763)
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2717)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:4150)
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:4)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you expect `%2n` to do?

Comment: Try `%2d`. `%n` is newline. Not iNteger. Also, `System.out.printf` is a thing you might use. `for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) { System.out.printf("%2d * %2d = %2d%n", 5, i, 5 * i); }`

Comment: `"%2n"` -> `"%2d"`

Comment: *"to right align by 2 space"* - That's not what the javadocs for `Formatter` says will happen: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA - We know.  But you don't mention the javadoc in your answer ... or attempt to *explain* what was wrong with the OP's version.   And ... did you **really** have to post a link to an image?  See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  The information could easily be conveyed without a pesky image ... which renders with ridiculously tiny writing in my browser.

Comment: @StephenC  Thanks for your comments. I have edited my answer as per your comment.

Comment: Ahem ... you *half* addressed *one* of the three things I commented about :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To format an integer to a width of 2, you should use "d" instead of
> "n".

You need to change system.out print line of code from

```
System.out.println(" 5 * "+ String.format("%2n", i) + " = " + (5*i));
```

**To**

```
System.out.println(" 5 * " + String.format("%2d", i) + " = " + (5 * i));
```

Your final code will be :

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(" 5 * " + String.format("%2d", i) + " = " + (5 * i));
        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
5 *  1 = 55 *  2 = 10
 5 *  3 = 15
 5 *  4 = 20
 5 *  5 = 255 *  6 = 30
 5 *  7 = 35
5 *  8 = 40
 5 *  9 = 45
5 * 10 = 50
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the original code, String.format("%2n", i) is not a valid format specifier. The %n format specifier is used to insert a newline character, not to format a number. To format a number with a specific width, you should use %2d instead, where 2 is the width.

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format(" 5 * %2d = %2d", i, 5*i));
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, `String.format(" 5 * %2d = %2d", i, 5*i)` creates a formatted string where `%2d` is used to format the two integer values `i` and `5*i` with a width of 2 characters.